# List objects of logged current user

Tags: python, django, web

I would like to ask how I could list all objects of logged current user via class based view in django.

I have two apps in the project. One is called users and the other one is badminton.

users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

badminton/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from users import models as users_models 

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(users_models.Profile ,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    matches_played = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

class Match(models.Model):
    player_home = models.OneToOneField(Player, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, related_name='player_home')
    player_away = models.OneToOneField(Player, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, related_name='player_away')
```

How I can access all matches of logged user via queryset? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list `Matche`s for which the `request.user` has as `Player` object `player_home` and/or `player_away` for that match with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Match.objects.filter(
    Q(player_home__name__user=request.user) |
    Q(player_away__name__user=request.user)
)
```

> **Note**: A foreign key refers to an *object*, not to the string representation of that
>   object. Therefore `name` is not really a good name to refer to a `Profile` object. You
>   might want to consider renaming it to `profile`.

Comment: I tried this filter and it throw this kind of error: Cannot query "pipikej": Must be "Profile" instance. pipikej is username of the logged user.

Comment: @pipikej: Did you use `request.user`, or `request.user.username`? I indeed made a small mistake, the edit should fix this.

Comment: I used request.user.